# Android launch icon doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, launch

I'm having problems with setting my launcher icon from my android app.

As you can see, i've named the logo `logodoor.png` in the folder drawable (too in drawable hdpi, ldpi, etc.), and in `AndroidManifest.xml` `drawable/logodoor`

*When starting up the app, it won't show the right launch icon, but the standard no-icon-android-icon.* 
-> On the target device the icon isn't displayed good; like there is a logo for twitter too

thanks for your answer :)

Menno

Manifest code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.menno.ghlyceum" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.4">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/logodoor" android:label="Ghlyceum OB" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Notes" />
        <activity android:name=".Help"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Rooster"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I've had to uninstall the app for the icon to change

Comment: True, I tried the app on 3 different devices and reinstalled sometimes :(

Comment: Are you certain that you changed the drawable in xhdpi, hdpi, and mdpi? If so, try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you have something like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logodoor"
    ............>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logodoor"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivityname"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_flash_file" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This way you can put your my launcher icon in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: Where should I be able to set the icon displayed in the applications on the target device (such as your mail logo, twitter logo etc.)

Comment: I think it should be in the layout.xml.

Comment: I do mean this logos: http://janetalkstech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/jane-g1-apps-08072010.png

Comment: oh, it's not controlled by your application. When you long press an icon from system menu, the icon can be dragged to home screen.

Comment: What do you mean? My problem is that the icon isn't the right one. for example: the browser has a globe as icon. I want to have a heart as icon, but the user can't see that heart, just the standard android-icon, and the application name.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work either (see my question for the whole manifest code)

Comment: The code I pasted in the answer was copied from my project. No reason not work. So I think you may check if your file name matches.